# Using SVN, how do I selectively create a patch file?

Tags: windows, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have a codebase with several changes in it that are best split up into several commits.

In `git`, I would use `git add -p` to select the changes I wanted from each file and create a commit and pull request based on those.

I'm new to SVN and I'm wondering about the best way to achieve this? It looks like I can do file-level selection, but not changes within those files?

I'm using TortoiseSVN as my local version control tool, but I'm happy to use another tool (has to run on Windows) if there's one that will do what I want.

Comment: See this: https://twitter.com/visualsvn/status/977190471939313664

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something you won't get from SVN. Separating changes in your working area into multiple commit can only have a file granularity. You can't split changes from the same file into several commits.

So I'd say you should instead give a look at [how git-svn works](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion). It allows you to use Git over an SVN repository, with some limitations. You'll use `git dcommit` to push to the SVN repository for example. You must use a rebasing strategy over merging too. But otherwise, you get colored diffs, stash, rebasing, proper handling of multiple branches, proper formatting of patches by default, etc.

If you already know git, this will give you more, for less annoyance.

Comment: Downvoted because it *is* something you can get from SVN and VisualSVN.

Comment: Maybe there's a client that implements it but that's no SVN feature. In SVN you end up doing full checkouts when you need to work on different branches. BTW, the "commit this block" feature on VisualSVN is far from doing what Git does. Seems you have to commit block by block, whereas in git you can select your changes, then commit them at once.

Comment: 1) TortoiseSVN's "restore after commit" is not the same as partial commits. 2) Core SVN does not have such feature built-in right now, but checkpointing in a local working copy is on the SVN project's roadmap and I guess that it will make " select your changes, then commit them at once" possible in one of the upcoming updates.

Comment: In the meantime git has it all, and more. I've worked as an SVN integrator for about 2 × 1.5 years, and used SVN before that as a developper. I learned SVN before git, but once you learned to use git, returning back to SVN is just a pain.

Comment: Pain points I had especially is the network being involved in most operations (need to merge stuff but the server is down? Go home), the lack of stash, the [svn command line client needing to be worked around](https://github.com/liberforce/svn-hacks/blob/master/svn-hacks.sh) to have colored diffs, pagination, function context. That's why git-svn is IMHO the best option for someone that already knows git and has to work with svn.

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like I can do file-level selection, but not changes within those files?

This is easily possible with VisualSVN plug-in for Visual Studio 2017. The feature is called QuickCommit and it helps you partially commit selected changes in a file.

Use the **Commit this Block** and **Commit Selection** context menu commands in the Visual Studio editor.

Here is an animated screenshot:

[image]